# How do I print only files that contain the string only in my current directory in Bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I used that `ls -bl *.c | grep -r "string"`. However, the files in the sub directory are printed as well. How do I print only files that contain the string only in my current directory in Bash shell?

Comment: Why do you use `ls` at all? Why `grep -r` - you are not scanning a directory. You want to print all file __names__ that contain "string" or all files that contain "string"?

Comment: @KamilCuk I often wish `ls` would not output anything to stdout, but stderr or directly output to the tty so that its output could not be piped or captured for parsing. ;)

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to print all file names that contain "string" .

Comment: What's wrong with `echo *string*`, or `for f in *string*; do echo "$f"; done`?

Comment: `for f in *string*; do echo "$f"; done` just `printf "%s\n" *string*` then : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for a "string" in all .c files in current directory just pass the files to grep:

```
grep string *.c
```

`grep -r` **ignores standard input** and scans current directory recursively. `echo ignored | grep -r "string"` will work the same way as `grep -r "string"`.

Comment: @KamilCuk : Strange thing is that the OP in his comment explicitly said that he wants _to print all file **names** that contain "string"_, hence I would expect the string to be found  in the name, not in the content.

Comment: @namsan so, your comment is misleading :) you are searching for files that file _content_ contains the "string", not files that are _named_ with the "string".